# Is there possibility to join these two shapes with the help of adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

There is an issue while making the curved arrow. I tried to use curve tool to make the arrow but it looks weird when I need to add the arrow head on it. Also the size of arrow is different then the curve being generated by me.

Please find the reference image attached with this message. [image]

**Goal** is to create similar diagram showed in this image: [image: goal image]

Comment: What have you tried? Extend the curve till it overlaps and and shape build? >But then why do that when redrawing is easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a curved path, then in the Stroke panel, add a stroke, add an arrow head, adjust the scale as required. For the Align, choose the "Place arrow tip at end of path" option.

Example

[image]

Comment: is there any suggestion to make the perfect curved path? The pen tool helped me to make one but, the path where curve turns back looks bit weird!

Comment: @python You could use an ellipse and then simply delete half of it